# Selenium confirm position of cursor

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, automated-tests, capybara

I've been trying to find a way to confirm that the cursor is within an input field (to simulate clicking within that field).

There's a scenario where an error message is invoked at the top of a webpage if a field entry fails validation.

The error message is a hyperlink that when pressed, scrolls to point in the page where that input field is and it places the cursor within the field.

Is there a way to confirm the cursor is in the box?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the cursor is in a text field, that means the text field is in focus or is the active element. Capybara does not directly provide a method for this. However, there are a couple of options.

**Switch to the active element**

If you drop down to the underlying Selenium driver, you can retrive the active element:

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.active_element
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x34409cfc id="0.6429182184051125-3">
```

With the active element, you can check that it is the element you expect:

```
# Use Capybara to find the element you expect to be in focus
expected_element = page.find("#field_id")

# Get the element that is actually in focus
active_element = page.driver.browser.switch_to.active_element

# Check that the two elements are the same
# Note that you need to call `native` so that you are comparing Selenium elements
expect(active_element).to eq(expected_element)
```

**Use `evaluate_script`**

An alternative approach is to use JavaScript to get some detail about the active element. For example, the following returns the id of the element in focus:

```
active_id = page.evaluate_script("document.activeElement.id")
expect(active_id).to eq('field_id')
```

Comment: I have tried both solutions. When evaluating Javascript, I get expected to find x but got nil.

Comment: After adding a 2 second sleep between the click and expectation, it worked. Thank you